# Probability of winning the jackpot at a certain state's lottery

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations, lotteries

> A certain state's lottery consists of choosing $6$ numbers at random without replacement from the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots,40\}$.  What is the probability that someone wins the jackpot?

I just want to make sure my answer of $\left( \frac{1}{40} \right)^6$ is the correct approach to the situation.  Whatever that answer is I have not computed it yet.

Comment: Is order of selection important? (I.e., do you have to match the numbers in a certain order?)

Comment: The question did not specify, so I assume order is not important

Answer (score 3):

Assuming order is not important, there are $40\choose 6$ ways to choose the six numbers.  So the probability of getting the correct six numbers with one ticket is $\frac{1}{40\choose 6}=\frac{(6!)(34!)}{40!}$